# Twitter share issue checking in HTML5 Validation

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter

i am using twitter to share my post in wordpress. It works fine while sharing, but while checking in HTML5 validation it shows the error " for attribute href on element a: Whitespace in query component. Use %20 in place of spaces."

My twitter share code is,

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
```

Error shows that use %20 in place of spaces. But i dont know where to include the %20 in above share code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_title(); ?> <?php the_permalink(); ?>
                     ^ there
```

However, `the_title();` does not output properly encoded text, so you should pass it through `urlencode()`

So it should be:

```
<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>%20<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```